# How to run an amd64 docker images on arm64 host

Tags: python-3.x, docker, tensorflow

WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
2021-07-28 22:25:06.349222: F tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:37] The TensorFlow library was compiled to use AVX instructions, but these aren't available on your machine.

I am trying to run an amd64 image on arm64, I tried adding --platform Linux/amd64, but still the same issue.

Any workarounds?

Comment: Can you reword your headline as a specific question? This will get more people to look at your question.

Comment: What is the question? This is just a warning message, not an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build the image for amd64, change the default environment variable as below:

```
export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64
docker build -t mytag:myver .
```

Then you can inspect to verify the architecture:

```
docker image inspect mytag:myver | grep -i Architecture
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have changed the architecture and built the docker image. When I ran the docker image, the following error shows up "F tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:37] The TensorFlow library was compiled to use AVX instructions, but these aren't available on your machine." I even tried with Anaconda Python.

Comment: From what I see, Anaconda should work for older CPUs. Can you please try again following this blog post? https://www.anaconda.com/blog/tensorflow-in-anaconda